# Pandas, selecting a subset of a dataframe using a series

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df.

```
+----------+------------+-------------+-----+--+
|   City   | First_name | Last_name   | Age |  |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----+--+
| London   | Han        | Solo        |  34 |  |
| Paris    | Luke       | Skywalker   |  30 |  |
| New York | Leia       | Organa      |  30 |  |
| LA       | Lando      | calrissian  |  40 |  |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----+--+
```

and a (pandas) series btained from a separate, smaller df (df2) using .loc[:,'Age']

```
+------------+
|    Age     |
+------------+
|    30      |
|    30      |
+------------+
```

I would like to select all of the rows in df1 using the information in the series. Giving something like this,

```
+----------+------------+-------------+-----+--+
|   City   | First_name | Last_name   | Age |  |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----+--+
| Paris    | Luke       | Skywalker   |  30 |  |
| New York | Leia       | Organa      |  30 |  |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----+--+
```

I have looked at the literature for .loc and .iloc, but this doesn't seem to be what I am after. I was trying to write a small for loop, but have limited experience (I'm new to programming). Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: `df1[df1.Age.isin(df2.Age)`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming larger df is `df1` and smaller one is `df2`, extract out the values of age which you want to select:

`mask = df2['Age'].unique()`

Then simply query `df1` by this `mask`:

`df1.loc[df1['Age'].isin(mask)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the dataframes directly:

```
df[df['Age'] == df2['Age']]
```