# Use a Series object to select rows from a dataframe (in Python using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a Series object that looks like this:

```
traffic_id_1    GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590A_V_0460A_ID_8481
traffic_id_2      GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590_V_0460_ID_1149
traffic_id_3              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrl0325ra
traffic_id_4              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0325ra
traffic_id_5              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0328ra
Name: 176, dtype: object
```

Now I want to select rows from a dataframe (it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4TVu.png)) that contain these IDs, using this Series object.

**TL;DR**
What is the most basic way to this?

Extra info:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684506/pandas-selecting-a-subset-of-a-dataframe-using-a-series) post and that way seems to work for me, but I'm following a course for my study and they haven't taught me the .isin() attribute yet. That doesn't mean that I can't use it, but I want to able to do it with only the knowledge that I have from the course.

I am working in Jupyter notebook and have imported pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot and seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful for you, since you seem to want to do it based on what you've covered in the course, something we don't have access to. But you can compare series and a dataframe with `reindex`, after setting the relevant col as index.

Here is a reproducible example:

Your data:

```
traffic_id_1    GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590A_V_0460A_ID_8481
traffic_id_2      GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590_V_0460_ID_1149
traffic_id_3              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrl0325ra
traffic_id_4              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0325ra
traffic_id_5              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0328ra
```

(Copied to clipboard, then:)

```
# make series into df
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
# pull out original series from df column
ser = pd.Series(df['b'].values, df['a'].values).copy()
# change some values in the original
df.loc[1, 'b'] = 'foo'
df.loc[3, 'b'] = 'bar'
```

So the dataframe is:

```
    a               b
0   traffic_id_1    GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590A_V_0460A_ID_8481
1   traffic_id_2    foo
2   traffic_id_3    RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrl0325ra
3   traffic_id_4    bar
4   traffic_id_5    RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0328ra
```

And the series:

```
traffic_id_1    GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590A_V_0460A_ID_8481
traffic_id_2      GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590_V_0460_ID_1149
traffic_id_3              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrl0325ra
traffic_id_4              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0325ra
traffic_id_5              RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0328ra
dtype: object

# set index as relevant col
df = df.set_index('b')

df.reindex(ser).dropna()
```

Output:

```
                                        a
GEO03_D4T-RWS_I_6590A_V_0460A_ID_8481   traffic_id_1
RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrl0325ra             traffic_id_3
RWS01_MONIBAS_0351hrr0328ra             traffic_id_5
```

Edit: you can also achieve this with a boolean filter. Omitting the step of setting the index in the dataframe:

```
mask = df.b == ser.reset_index(drop=True)
df[mask]
```

yields the same thing. (Or in one line: `df[df.b == ser.reset_index(drop=True)]`). Note that it's necessary to get rid of the series' unique index, so that it aligns with that of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! It's not something I've learned, but it's still useful to know another way :)

But do you think there's maybe a way to create a boolean mask of some sort? Because that's something I have learned.